# PHP - C Shared Memory

Tags: php, c, shared-memory

I am trying to write to a memory address from PHP and read from C. I can write successfully from PHP and read again from PHP end using this ;

```
$key = ftok("shmfile", 't');
$shm_id = shmop_open($key, "c", 0666, 100);
if (!$shm_id) {
    echo "Couldn't create shared memory segment.";
}
$data = "Hello, World!";
$bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, $data, 0);
if ($bytes_written != strlen($data)) {
    echo "Couldn't write the entire data to shared memory.";
} else {
    echo "Successfully wrote {$bytes_written} bytes to shared memory.\n";
}
$data_read = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 100);
if (!$data_read) {
    echo "Couldn't read from shared memory segment.";
} else {
    echo "Data read from shared memory: " . $data_read . "\n";
}
shmop_close($shm_id);
echo "Shared memory segment closed.";
```

and my C code is as following;

```
int main()
{
    // ftok to generate unique key
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65);

    // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
    int shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // shmat to attach to shared memory
    char* str = (char*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

    cout << "Data read from memory:" << str;

    // detach from shared memory
    shmdt(str);

    // destroy the shared memory
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

but when I run C code I get a segfault. I think I need to make some modifications in my C code to read what PHP has written.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where does the fault occur?

Comment: Fault occurs when I execute C executable from console to read what PHP wrote to shmfile

Comment: Why don't you test the return value of `shmget()`? And why are you using the `IPC_CREAT` flag?

Comment: @Olivier I can't test the return value since I get the fault and I am using `IPC_CREAT` because it existed in one of the examples I was working on that seemed to work

Comment: What I meant was, exactly which line of your C code causes the fault?

Comment: You're most likely getting the fault *after* `shmget()`, when you're trying to access the `str` pointer. You **should** test the return value of `shmget()`, precisely to avoid faults.

Comment: *"because it existed in one of the examples I was working on"* Instead of copying code without undertanding it, I suggest reading the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

You use `shm_open()` for C and PHP.